# Pandas update and add rows one dataframe with key column in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 data frames with identical columns. Column 'key' will have unique values.

Data frame 1:-

```
A B key C    
0 1 k1  2    
1 2 k2  3    
2 3 k3  5
```

Data frame 2:-

```
A B key C    
4 5 k1  2    
1 2 k2  3
2 3 k4  5
```

I would like to update rows in Dataframe-1 with values in Dataframe -2 if key in Dataframe -2 matches with Dataframe -1.
Also if key is new then add entire row from Dataframe-2 to Dataframe-1.

Final Output Dataframe is like this with same columns.

```
A B key C
4 5 k1  2   --> update
1 2 k2  3   --> no changes
2 3 k3  5   --> no changes
2 3 k4  5   --> new row
```

I have tried with below code. I need only 4 columns 'A', 'B','Key','C' without any suffixes after merge.

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2,on='key',how='outer')
>>> df3
   A_x  B_x key  C_x  A_y  B_y  C_y
0  0.0  1.0  k1  2.0  4.0  5.0  2.0
1  1.0  2.0  k2  3.0  1.0  2.0  3.0
2  2.0  3.0  k3  5.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
3  NaN  NaN  k4  NaN  2.0  3.0  5.0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you're looking for `combine_first`.

```
a = df2.set_index('key')
b = df1.set_index('key')

(a.combine_first(b)
  .reset_index()
  .reindex(columns=df1.columns))

     A    B key    C
0  4.0  5.0  k1  2.0
1  1.0  2.0  k2  3.0
2  2.0  3.0  k3  5.0
3  2.0  3.0  k4  5.0
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
df1 = {'key': ['k1', 'k2', 'k3'], 'A':[0,1,2], 'B': [1,2,3], 'C':[2,3,5]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=df1)
print (df1)
df2 = {'key': ['k1', 'k2', 'k4'], 'A':[4,1,2], 'B': [5,2,3], 'C':[2,3,5]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=df2)
print (df2)
df3 = df1.append(df2)
df3.drop_duplicates(subset=['key'], keep='last', inplace=True)
df3 = df3.sort_values(by=['key'], ascending=True)
print (df3)
```

Comment: you should comment your line "df3 = df1.merge(df2,on='key',how='outer')"

Comment: It's not updating the values of first row. It's keeping the values from first dataframe. 
Merge condition is :-
inline `For each key in dataframe2:
    if key is present in dataframe1:
        update the row values
    else:
       add the row`

Comment: I've written the all code now. What version of python are you using?

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to indicate index columns:

```
df1.set_index('key', inplace=True)
df2.set_index('key', inplace=True)
```

Then, combine the dataframes to get all the index keys in place (this will not update the df1 values! See: [combine_first manual](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html)):

```
df1 = df1.combine_first(df2)
```

Last step is updating the values in df1 with df2 and resetting the index

```
df1.update(df2)
df1.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to append and remove duplicates:

```
df3 = pd.drop_duplicates(df1.append(df2))
```

Comment: It's not removing suffixes.
df3 = df3.drop_duplicates(df1.append(df2))
>>> df3 
A_x  B_x key  C_x  A_y  B_y  C_y
0  0.0  1.0  k1  2.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  1.0  2.0  k2  3.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
2  2.0  3.0  k3  5.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
3  NaN  NaN  k4  NaN  2.0  3.0  5.0

Answer (score 0):

assumes both dataframes have the same index columns

```
df3 = df1.combine_first(df2)
df3.update(df2)
```

Answer (score 0):

After setting the same column as index on each dataframe:

```
def df_upsert(df1, df2):
    df = df1.combine_first(df2)
    df.update(df2)
    return df
```